# Call method from form to sendMails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0, gsp

I want to send an email from a form to a list of email addresses:

Thats my form:

```
        <g:form url="[resource:contactInstance, action:'notify']">
            <!-- START FORM -->

            <fieldset class="form">

                <div
                    class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: contactInstance, field: 'firstName', 'error')} required">
                    <label for="firstName"> <g:message
                            code="contact.firstName.label" default="First Name" /> <span
                        class="required-indicator">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <g:textField name="firstName" required=""
                        value="${contactInstance?.firstName}" />
                </div>

                <div
                    class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: contactInstance, field: 'lastName', 'error')} required">
                    <label for="lastName"> <g:message
                            code="contact.lastName.label" default="Last Name" /> <span
                        class="required-indicator">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <g:textField name="lastName" required=""
                        value="${contactInstance?.lastName}" />
                </div>

                <div
                    class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: contactInstance, field: 'email', 'error')} required">
                    <label for="email"> <g:message code="contact.email.label"
                            default="Email" /> <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <g:textField name="email" required=""
                        value="${contactInstance?.email}" />
                </div>

                <div
                    class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: contactInstance, field: 'description', 'error')} required">
                    <label for="description"> <g:message
                            code="contact.description.label" default="Description" /> <span
                        class="required-indicator">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <g:textField name="description" required=""
                        value="${contactInstance?.description}" />
                </div>


            </fieldset>

            <fieldset class="buttons">
                <g:submitButton name="create" class="notify"
                    value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
            </fieldset>

            <!-- END FORM -->
        </g:form>
```

Thats my `ContactController.groovy`

```
@Secured(['permitAll'])
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class ContactController {

    private static final log = LogFactory.getLog(this)

    static allowedMethods = [notify: "POST"]

    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond Contact.list(params), model:[contactInstanceCount: Contact.count()]
    }

    /**
     * Sends a Mail to a specified list of email addresses
     * @param sender
     * @param receiver
     * @param templateName
     * @param params
     * @return
     */
    def void notify(Contact contactInstance) {

        log.info("call notify method")

        EmailSettings emailAddresses = new EmailSettings()

        if (emailAddresses.list() == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        mailService.sendMail {

            log.info("send email to address list")

            multipart true
            from 
            to emailAddresses.list().toArray()
            subject "[Customer Notification]  " +  contactInstance.firstName + " " + contactInstance.lastName
            body contactInstance.description

        }

        request.withFormat {
            form {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'Contact.label', default: 'Contact'), contactInstance.id])
                redirect contactInstance
            }
            '*'{ respond contactInstance, [status: OK] }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that my method does not get called. Any recommendations what I should change.(besides I do not get an error message)

I really appreciate your answer!

PS.: Configuration of the mail plugin should be ok, because `spring security UI plugin` works!

**UPDATE**

Changing deleting `void` from the notify method I get this error:

```
compiler.GrailsProjectWatcher File [C:\Users\User\GrailsWorkspace\TestApp\grails-app\controllers\com\TestApp\ContactController.groovy] changed. Applying changes to application.
.....compiler.GrailsProjectWatcher Compilation Error: startup failed:
C:\Users\User\GrailsWorkspace\TestApp\grails-app\controllers\com\TestApp\ContactController.groovy: -1: The return type of java.lang.Object notify() in com.TestApp.ContactController is incompatible with void notify() in java.lang.Object
. At [-1:-1]  @ line -1, column -1.
1 error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call method from view. Change `notify` to an action. Just Remove `void` form `notify`

```
def notify(Contact contactInstance) {
```

**EDIT............................................................................**

Change name of the action `notify` because `notify method` [already exists in Object Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29). Error in my Intellij Idea:

```
Method notify() cannot override mthod notify() in java.lang.Object: override method is final.
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! Please have a look at my update, cause I am getting an error...

Comment: Change name of the action because `notify` method already exists in parent object. Error in my Intellij Idea: `Method notify() cannot override mthod notify() in java.lang.Object: override method is final`.

Comment: Thx a lot great answer! You helped me a lot! However, I still get an exception: `No such property: mailService ` Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Inject mailService service in your controller `def mailService`.